# My name is Katey, and I know what your question is

Tags: discussion

The answer is YES, I do love cherry pie! Oh… you didn’t ask that? Well… now you made this is awkward!

Since I'm here, I will introduce myself. My name is Katey and I work for Stack Exchange as a member of the newish CHAOS team!

Over the next few days, I will be scuttling around and editing entries and titles for clarity. CHAOS has a set of guidelines to follow when improving questions, but we aren't out to step on anyone's toes. In general, I am just revising for spelling, grammar, and overall clarity. If I edit your question (or a question you've already edited) and you don't agree with the changes I've made, feel free to roll them back.

However, I won't be editing questions here in meta, but I will be dropping in to say hi and see what's going on - so feel free to let me know if you have any questions, concerns or complaints.

You can follow me on twitter @KateyCHAOS, so feel free to do that so I can follow you back! You can also follow the whole team on our StackHQ tumblr: http://stackexchange.tumblr.com/

---

Edit: Another aspect of my role with CHAOS is to find cool things to foster community on this site, so please let me know if there are any ideas you've had percolating.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share some of your guidelines on what's a bad title, when should we edit, what's a good question title, etc. We have a number of users who edit titles, and if there is a best practice, please share.

Comment: I am following the mod's leads here, and trying to adhere to the FAQ. I personally tend to gravitate towards making questions into question form. I may rearrange to the active voice if I think the question or is worded confusingly.

Comment: Welcome Katey, great to have you here! @yossarian, check out the [original meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100137/141911) - in fact, I think the recent spate of title-editing has probably been following CHAOS's lead from other sites.

Comment: Where is the _Ψ_ that should be associated to CHAOS's members? `:-)`

Comment: Ooh, good question - it's been added to my profile and it should show up... I will investigate. Thanks @kiamlaluno!

Comment: I found my psi!

Comment: Hi Katie, Welcome!

Comment: @Katey Ψ , hi, want to go get coffee and π some time?

Comment: @mfg Mmmmm, π...

Comment: @KateyΨ, did you lose your mini-mod status? Your edits are showing up for mod approval now.

Comment: @yossarian Yeah, we only had that temporarily. Sorry if I am being a bother!

Comment: No bother. Just wondering what had happened.